# Creating a framework and using pods in it, and call this whole framework in a project Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a query, i am converting my project into a framework..
All the pods are installed in my code already, i have created the framework by simply selecting Framework, then i just created a class to expose my SDK

Then to make my SDK universal i had to add the Aggregate target , my framework builds fine and lets me access any Pod inside my framework files, but when i try to export my framework by pressing Cmd + B on my Aggregate target i am getting this error, i have attached screenshot.

If i use my framework without adding PODS to it, it works absolutely fine whenever i build the aggregate it gives me the framework, but the problem is occuring when i install PODS in the framework and then try to build it.

Summary:
Framework is not building if Pods are installed.

Aggregate is failing every time when pods are installed

Comment: You can’t put pods in a framework

Comment: so how i will use my libraries then? using framework to project

Comment: You can’t use libraries in frameworks